# In informatica cloud, which connection type should I use to access a dynamically generated URL that provides the location of a CSV file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, csv, integration, informatica

I have a integration process that obtains a URL to a CSV file.  The URL to the file is dynamically generated, but it is consistently hosted on Amazon S3, which we don't have an account on.  (The API endpoint which provides) the URL to the CSV is not on Amazon S3, it's a proprietary system.

The file is time-limited and the authentication to access the file is passed over in the URL.

The URL syntax I'm provided is similar to:
https://application-name.s3.amazonaws/directory/filename.csv?several_authentication_parameters

I can get to the point of parsing out the URL (if it's even needed), but I still can't figure out what type of connection or method to use to connect to the CSV server. I've tried using ReST v2 but can't  get it to save because the response is CSV (not json/xml as informatica is expecting).  The flatfile connectors seem to require the file be hosted locally. Do I need to download the file to the secure agent server first?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case its useful to others.  It appears Informatica Cloud doesn't have the ability to make a generic HTTP GET call.  The solution was to write a script, that the secure agent will execute, and execute a simple cURL to download the csv and store on the secure agent.  The CSV can then be a Source in mappings.  The design transformation to use in a Task Flow is "Command Task", which allows you to execute a script and pass in parameters.